# API Call after rendering UI in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app, in most cases, I need to make an API call to get some data that needs to be presented to the user. I handle them like this in my `InitAsync()` method in my view model which is invoked by `OnAppearing()` of the content page:

```cs
internal async Task InitAsync()
{
   IsBusy = true;

   var data = await _apiService.GetSomeData();
   if(data != null)
      SomeProperty = data; // The SomeProperty would be consumed by some UI element

   IsBusy = false;
}
```

However, there are cases when I need to fetch some data for later use or simply make an API call but I don't want the user to wait for this to be done. Not a traditional background operation but similar to it in that it's not time sensitive or really critical. The main objective is to render my UI without waiting for the API call's results.

Is a fire-and-forget call the appropriate approach in those cases?

```cs
internal async Task InitAsync()
{
   IsBusy = true;

   var data = await _apiService.GetSomeData();
   if(data != null)
      SomeProperty = data;

   IsBusy = false;

   Task.Run(() => {
      var dataForLaterUse = await _apiService.GetMoreData(); // dataForLaterUse would not be associated with a UI element
   });
}
```

How do I handle these API calls that should happen after the UI is made available to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm getting your problem. If your concern is that the user will have to wait for `InitAsync()` to complete in order to see the UI, then you don't have a problem.

`OnAppearing()` is not blocking for the UI, it's simply an event fired when the page appears. So you don't need to use `Task.Run()` to make sure that `OnAppearing()` ends as soon as possible. If you're calling the non-UI API after the UI-API, you're okay with the usability.

So, there shouldn't be any issues to have simply

```cs
internal async Task InitAsync()
{
   IsBusy = true;

   var data = await _apiService.GetSomeData();
   if(data != null)
      SomeProperty = data;

   IsBusy = false;

   var dataForLaterUse = await _apiService.GetMoreData(); // dataForLaterUse would not be associated with a UI element
}
```

If I may, a couple of suggestions.

> I handle them like this in my InitAsync() method in my view model which is invoked by OnAppearing() of the content page

Be careful using `OnAppearing()` to initialize viewmodels. This event isn't fired only when the page is created, but also in some other cases. I'm quite sure that it would be fired if the app goes to the background and it's then restored. Same if you display and dispose an alert. Not 100% sure this happens on each platform, but you should take it into account.

About fire-and-forget methods, you should always be careful on how you define them.
For example, if you wrap your code in a `try-catch` block and an exception is raised inside `_apiService.GetMoreData();`, you wouldn't catch it because the code inside the `try` block ends to be executed before the exception is thrown.

Lastly, using `Task.Run()` forces another thread to be used. While this may be desired in some cases, you may want to be careful about UI updates, which have to be performed always inside UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. As per wiring `OnAppearing()` to the view model, how would you invoke an initialization method in the view model without using `OnAppearing()` provided that some API calls need to be made during initialization so constructor approach isn’t the best?

Comment: It all depends on what you need. I'm not saying using `OnAppearing()` is wrong, only that it can have some undesired effects. I would say that, if done wisely, calling  initialization APIs from a method invoked in the constructor could be a reasonable way.